# Regex to match url segment only if not preceded by specific parent segment

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the last segment of a url, if and only if it is not preceded by a specific segment ('news-events').  So, for example, I would like to match 'my-slug' here:

```
http://example.com/my-slug
```

...but not here:

```
http://example.com/news-events/my-slug
```

I'm working with javascript -- have tried something like this:

```
\b(?!news-events)(\/\w+)\b$
```

...but the word boundary approach doesn't work here, as the / char serves as a boundary between the segments (so, the last segment gets selected, whether or not it is preceded by 'news-events'.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks much.

Comment: Try this `(?!\/news-events)(\/[^\/]+)$`

Comment: Thanks Titus, but couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Maybe the trailing slashes that you've mentioned in comments are the problem. Add an optional slash to the end of the pattern to support those `(?!\/news-events)(\/[^\/]+)\/?$` here is an example https://regex101.com/r/KwhJyQ/1

Comment: @Titus - thanks for the additional feedback.  Issue with this approach is that the slug gets selected both with and without the preceding segment string, where it should only be selected if the preceding string (news-events) is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***updated for optional trailing slash***

---

Don't be fooled, this is a tricky regex.

`/^(?:(?!news-events\/[^\/\r\n]*\/?$).)*?\/([^\/\r\n]+)\/?$/`

The segment is in capture group 1.

https://regex101.com/r/hrLqRq/3

```
 ^     
 (?:
      (?! news-events/ [^/\r\n]* /? $ )
      . 
 )*?
 / 
 ( [^/\r\n]+ )                 # (1)
 /?
 $
```

Comment: Thanks sln - this works nicely, but I'm finding some of my urls have trailing slashes as well.  Is there an adjustment that would allow an optional slash at the end of the url?

Comment: @Jegra Yes there is; just add `/?` to the very end of the regex :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim - I did try that, but it breaks the negation functionality (ie it selects all end segments, regardless of whether the preceding segment matches the 'news-events' string)

Comment: @Jegra - Updated for optional trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting the URL on forward slash, and then check that the second to last entry is *not* `news-events` and the last entry is `my-slug`.

```css
var url = 'http://example.com/news-events/my-slug';
var parts = url.split('/');
var n = parts.length

if (parts[n - 2] !== 'news-events' && parts[n - 1] === 'my-slug') {
    console.log("match")
}
else {
    console.log("no match")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - unfortunately, for my situation, the solution needs to be a single regex expression.

Comment: @Jegra Well perhaps this answer might be useful to someone else who doesn't have a regex restriction.  In my mind, splitting was much cleaner than a complex regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `.pathname` or the URL for one or more words

```js
let sources = [
  "http://example.com/my-slug"
, "http://example.com/news-events/my-slug"
];


let match = "/my-slug";

let not = "/news-events";

for (let src of sources) {
  let url = new URL(src);
  if (new RegExp(`^${not}${match}`).test(url.pathname)) {
    console.log("not", url.pathname)
  } else {
    if (new RegExp(`^${match}$`).test(url.pathname))
    console.log("ok", url.pathname)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guest271314 - unfortunately, for my situation, the solution needs to be a single regex expression.

Comment: @Jegra How is the `RegExp` used in the application? _"the solution needs to be a single regex expression."_ does not appear at text of original Question

Comment: apologies - should have included that specification in the original question.  Will be more specific in future.  Thanks again for the suggestion.