# Escaping characters within RegExp lookbehind assertions

Tags: javascript, regex

At [Regex to match url segment only if not preceded by specific parent segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783238/regex-to-match-url-segment-only-if-not-preceded-by-specific-parent-segment)

given the input

`http://example.com/my-slug` or `http://example.com/my-slug/`

the requirement is to match

`"my-slug"`

but not to match

`"my-slug"`

if preceded by

`"news-events"`

Was able to match `"/my-slug"` or `"/my-slug/"` by using [RegExp lookbehind assertions](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2016/02/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html) at Chromium with `--harmony` flag set with `RegExp`

```js
// why is the `\/` necessary following lookbehind?
let re = /(?<!news-events)\/[^/]+(?=\/$|$)/;

let sources = [
  "http://example.com/my-slug"
, "http://example.com/my-slug/"
, "http://example.com/news-events/my-slug"
];

for (let src of sources) {
  console.log(src.match(re))
}
```

however, when trying to precisely match `"my-slug"` without preceding `"/"` character by escaping the trailing `"/"` at `news-event/` the `RegExp` does not return same match, where the match for `"http://example.com/news-events/my-slug"` is `"y-slug"` when the expected result is `null`

```js
let re = /(?<!news-events\/)[^/]+(?=\/$|$)/;

let sources = [
  "http://example.com/my-slug"
, "http://example.com/my-slug/"
, "http://example.com/news-events/my-slug"
];

for (let src of sources) {
  console.log(src.match(re))
}
```

Questions:

- Why is the escaped `"/"` character not included as part of the `RegExp` lookbehind negation assertion?
- How to properly escape characters or otherwise adjust the `RegExp` lookbehind assertion to negate the full string `"news-events/"` and return the expected result `"my-slug"` without needing to include `\/` before portion of string which should be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this bit of the regular expression:

```
[^/]+(?=\/$|$)
```

matches the text `y-slug` (`y-slug` is multiple non-slash characters, optionally followed by a slash, followed by the end of the string), and `y-slug` is not preceded by `news-events/`, it’s a valid match. Since `my-slug` doesn’t match, it’s also the first valid match, so it’s the match that is returned.

You could add a second, positive lookbehind to indicate that any match must be a complete segment.

```js
let re = /(?<!news-events\/)(?<=\/)[^/]+(?=\/$|$)/;

let sources = [
  "http://example.com/my-slug"
, "http://example.com/my-slug/"
, "http://example.com/news-events/my-slug"
];

for (let src of sources) {
  console.log(src.match(re))
}
```

Comment: Why does the `RegExp` that does not return expected result when `\/` is included within lookbehind `[^/]+(?=\/$|$)` match `"y-slug"` and not `"my-slug"`?

Comment: @guest271314: Do you agree that `"y-slug"` matches `[^/]+(?=\/$|$)`?

Comment: Yes, though `"my-slug"` should be matched, yes? Why is the `"m"` not included within the match?

Comment: @guest271314: `"my-slug"` is a valid match for that part as well, but it’s not a valid match for `(?<!news-events\/)` because `news-events/` is before it. `"y-slug"` is acceptable because `news-events/` is not immediately before it (`news-events/m` is).

Comment: How does the `"m"` precisely get included or excluded from the match? Can you provide further description of "before it" and "not immediately before it"?

Comment: @guest271314: Let’s look a smaller example: `abb`. You want to match `b`s, so your regex is `/b+/` and it matches `"bb"`. All good. Now you want to not match `b`s if an `a` is before them. `/(?<!a)b+/` will match `"b"`, not null, because although `bb` doesn’t satisfy both `b+` and `(?<!a)`, `b` does.

Comment: The `"b"` you are referencing is the last `"b"` in the string, yes?

Comment: @guest271314: Put another way: 1) is there a match at index 0? "a" does not match `b+`, so no. 2) is there a match at index 1? "bb" matches `b+`, good, but it does not match `(?<!a)`. There is "a" before it. So no. 3) is there a match at index 2? "b" matches `b+`, and it also matches `(?<!a)` because there is not an "a" before it, so **yes**. This is the match.

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, that’s correct. I should have used `abc` and `[bc]+` for clarity. Sorry.